# Query is taking too much long time and impacting on our performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

Query is taking too much long time. This query comes from web aplication .
it was impacting on our performance.anybody please help me to rewrite it and share with me your valuable suggestions.

Query With Explain Plan:

```
mysql> explain SELECT DISTINCT(tab2.idnum) FROM (`tab2`) JOIN `tab1` ON tab1.question = tab2.idnum WHERE `department` = 'Biology' AND tab2.status != 'active' AND tab2.status != 'retired' AND (tab2.instructor = 164604 OR tab2.instructor = 194703) AND tab1.topic IN (SELECT `topic` FROM (`tab5`) JOIN `tab4` ON tab4.chapter = tab5.id WHERE `book` = 1000) AND tab2.idnum NOT IN (SELECT `question` FROM (`tab3`) WHERE `book` = 1000 AND `isPR` = 1) AND `questiontype` IN ('mult') limit 2;
+----+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table           | type            | possible_keys    | key     | key_len | ref                           | rows   | Extra                                     |
+----+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | tab1  | index           | question         | tq      | 8       | NULL                          | 149899 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | tab2  | eq_ref          | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY | 4       | comp1.tab1.question |      1 | Using where                               |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tab3 | unique_subquery | qb,question,book | qb      | 8       | func,const                    |      1 | Using where                               |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tab4  | ref             | chapter,topic    | topic   | 4       | func                          |      1 |                                           |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tab5     | eq_ref          | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY | 4       | comp1.tab4.chapter  |      1 | Using where                               |
+----+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table Structure:

```
mysql> show create table tab5\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab5
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab5` (
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `descrip` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `department` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `book` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_trial` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_live` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6305 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

mysql> show create table tab4\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab4
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab4` (
  `chapter` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `topic` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `chapter` (`chapter`),
  KEY `topic` (`topic`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table tab3\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab3
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab3` (
  `question` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isPR` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `qb` (`question`,`book`),
  KEY `question` (`question`),
  KEY `book` (`book`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table tab2 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab2
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab2` (
  `idnum` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `questiontype` enum('mult','CM','GO','FIB','AUD','HS','DD') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'def1',
  `question` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `difficulty` int(3) DEFAULT '0',
  `createdby` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `createdwhen` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `status` enum('active','calibrating','onhold','retired') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'def1',
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `child` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `family` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `department` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  `instructor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nmfilter` enum('everyone','majors only','undetermined') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'def1',
  `PR` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnum`),
  KEY `family` (`family`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=186724 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table tab1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab1` (
  `question` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `topic` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `question` (`question`),
  KEY `topic` (`topic`),
  KEY `tq` (`topic`,`question`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Avoid `DISTINCT`. Why are you using `IN` if there is only one value possible? Try replacing sub-selects by joins. Do you have indexes on the columns you are filtering?

Comment: please sent me that query.

Comment: As per your most recent question, please try to avoid expecting people to rewrite your queries for you - it is much better to ask for assistance, and then apply the advice you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complex one to analyze. Try to create sql fiddle to understand your problem better.
And my suggestion is, try to rewrite your query with JOIN only(remove nested queries) and try following query,

```
SELECT tab2.idnum
FROM (`tab2`) INNER JOIN `tab1` ON tab1.question = tab2.idnum INNER JOIN `tab3` ON tab2.idnum != tab3.question INNER JOIN `tab5` ON tab1.topic = tab5.topics
INNER JOIN `tab4` ON tab4.chapter = tab5.id 
WHERE 
tab5.department = 'Biology' AND tab2.status != 'active' AND tab2.status != 'retired' AND 
(tab2.instructor = 164604 OR tab2.instructor = 194703) 
AND tab5.book = 1000 AND tab3.book =  1000 AND tab3.isPR = 1
AND tab2.questiontype IN ('mult')
```

Note: Since I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, I remove some of the things like DISTINCT, LIMIT. But i hope this will give you idea about how to deal the problem.

To give more apporiate answer, just upadte your post with tables and data or create sqlfiddle and explain what you are trying to achieve from these table and how you are relate them.

EDIT:

```
SELECT tab2.idnum
FROM (`tab2`) INNER JOIN `tab1` ON tab1.question = tab2.idnum AND (tab2.status != 'active' AND tab2.status != 'retired' AND (tab2.instructor = 164604 OR tab2.instructor = 194703) AND tab2.questiontype IN ('mult')) 
INNER JOIN `tab3` ON tab2.idnum != tab3.question AND tab3.book =  1000 AND tab3.isPR = 1
INNER JOIN `tab5` ON tab1.topic = tab5.topics AND tab5.department = 'Biology' AND tab5.book = 1000
INNER JOIN `tab4` ON tab4.chapter = tab5.id
```

Note: To increase speed make sure about your indexing, how many rows present in table and limit the result of query.

EDIT2:

```
SELECT tab2.idnum
FROM `tab2` INNER JOIN `tab1` ON tab1.question = tab2.idnum AND (tab2.status != 'active' AND tab2.status != 'retired' AND (tab2.instructor = 164604 OR tab2.instructor = 194703) AND tab2.questiontype IN ('mult')) 
INNER JOIN `tab3` ON tab2.idnum != tab3.question AND tab3.book =  1000 AND tab3.isPR = 1
INNER JOIN `tab5` ON tab5.department = 'Biology' AND tab5.book = 1000
INNER JOIN `tab4` ON tab4.chapter = tab5.id
WHERE tab1.topic = tab4.topic
```

Comment: @pvr, I have edited my post and make sure things which are mentioned in "Note". If problem still persist, then give your tables in http://sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Please find the sql fiddle link here .Above query is throwing errors.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1b57/4

Comment: Please update sqlfiddle with some dummy data. Try part of query presented in EDIT2